# Shortest code to cycle through RGB LEDs

Tags: code-golf

Given four RGB LEDs and 8 colors, your task is to light up each LED in order with a color, and cycle through the LEDs as you cycle through the colors; with only one LED lit up at a time.

So for 8 colors across 4 RGB LEDs, it would look like this (at a hardware level (since there are three channels for each LED)):

```
LED1            LED2            LED3            LED4
0xFF,0x00,0x00  OFF             OFF             OFF
OFF             0xFF,0XA5,0x00  OFF             OFF
OFF             OFF             0xFF,0XFF,0x00  OFF
OFF             OFF             OFF             0x00,0xFF,0x00
0x00,0x0,0xFF   OFF             OFF             OFF
OFF             0xFF,0X00,0xFF  OFF             OFF
OFF             OFF             0xFF,0X00,0xFF  OFF
OFF             OFF             OFF             0xFF,0xC0,0xCB
```

#### Inputs:

None

#### Program End Condition:

User presses the `SpaceBar` key.

#### Program Behavior

There should be a 500ms delay between each LED shift, and each LED will remain "Lit" for 1 second (in our case; this simply means that should the user press the spacebar *before the next color is shown*, then the currently "lit" LED will be chosen.  This should happen until the user presses the spacebar.

At that point, output the color the user has chosen.

```
%> myprog
   LED      COLOR 
   ---    --------
    1     0xFF0000
    2     0xFFA500
    3     0xFFFF00
    4     0x00FF00
    1     0x0000FF
    2     0xFF00FF
```

#### Output:

```
1: 
2: 0xFF00FF 
3: 
4:
```

Just because they're beautiful, and to make it a little harder, I chose Magenta and Pink for the final two colors.

#### Win Condition

The winning condition is the shortest amount of code in bytes to implement this function.

Any language that is capable of being run from the command line is eligible (although if there's a JavaScript version for the browser that wins; that'd also be interesting).

Comment: It still looks unclear to me. Exactly what input do we need to take?

Comment: I get that there's no input but  I don't see any mention of a spacebar in the spec :-S ?? Also, it appears we are now allowed to output text to stdout? Can you show more of the cycle to show exactly what the output should be. It may seem like pedantry but if the spec is vague and open to interpretation, it makes it impossible to decide if an entry is valid or not.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Why is it still unclear after my edits?

Comment: "*Given four RGB LEDs, your task is to cycle through all the LEDs, **with one Color Per LED**, and only one LED displaying a color at a time. So **for 8 colors across 4 RGB LEDs*** ..." The spec appears to contradict itself within the first two sentences. If the intended question is "*Time how long it takes from program start until the user presses the spacebar, divide by 500ms, round down to an integer, take value modulo 8, and then output one of these 8 hard-coded outputs*" then that would IMO be a much clearer explanation than the current text.

Comment: @PeterTaylor edited.

Comment: Also, why does it matter that each LED stays lit for a full second if we only output the final choice?

Comment: @ThomasKwa To throw more of a challenge in there and to accurately reflect what would happen for a user. As far as the colors; those are chosen because they there is some variability there; you can't just do bitwise manipulation of a specific amount each time.  I will probably add my solution; but since I'm not a code-golfer generally, it'd probably be mocked mercilessly.

Comment: Please add your solution, and don't golf it. Without it I can't tell what the challenge is.

Comment: So the colors are fixed at exactly the ones in the first code block?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yes.

Comment: You said that my rewording of the problem wasn't what you intended, but the edit doesn't tell me what I misunderstood, so I still find it unclear.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm still not sure what you want out of me here. I'd love to edit it to fit whatever you find unclear; but we have a disconnect.

Comment: Which part of "*Time how long it takes from program start until the user presses the spacebar, divide by 500ms, round down to an integer, take value modulo 8, and then output one of these 8 hard-coded outputs*" is not correct? Or did you delete your comment because it is correct after all?

Comment: @PeterTaylor There are a few incorrect things there; we don't care about how long the user spends doing something. They could spend all eternity; we're not dividing by 500ms because each LED stays active for 1 second; so you have a potential of 2 seconds (or 1.5 seconds, depending) where the state could be active; "take value modulo 8" and the '8 hardcoded outputs' matter; part of the program is the most efficient way to write those hardcoded values to their output (in this case, the LED).

Comment: 2 seconds or 1.5 seconds depending on what? Could you provide a reference implementation?